# Python Pandas - Rename and merge of 3 datasets

Tags: python, pandas, merge, rename

I want to change the common variables' name for the 3 datasets
and then merge them but it seems that the rename doesn't change var name as EID,
how can I solve it?

Also, can I merge 3 datasets using pd.merge command, instead of doing 1:1 for all?

Thanks

```
data1516 = pd.read_csv('C:/data2015_2016.csv', sep='|', names=None, header=1, encoding='latin-1')    
data1617 = pd.read_csv('C:/data2016_2017.csv', sep='|', names=None, header=1, encoding='latin-1')    
data1718 = pd.read_csv('C:/data2017_2018.csv', sep='|', names=None, header=1, encoding='latin-1')

data1516.rename(index=str, columns={"Employer: ID" : "EID"})    
data1617.rename(index=str, columns={"Employer: ID" : "EID"})    
data1718.rename(index=str, columns={"Employer: ID" : "EID"})    
data1517 = pd.merge(data1516, data1617, on='EID', how='outer')
```

Comment: assign it back `data1516=data1516.rename(index=str, columns={"Employer: ID" : "EID"})`

Comment: Thanks ! but I still get a keyerror after adding them.

Comment: KeyError: 'EID'

Comment: Add it as answer. please check

Comment: Did for all already :) thx

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
dfs = [data1516, data1617, data1718]
df = pd.concat([x.rename(columns={"Employer: ID" : "EID"}) for x in dfs], axis=1)
```

Comment: Btw for simple inquiry, is there any way to do this using merge instead of concat?

Comment: seems if we can seting the EID as index should be better right ?

Comment: @Nora, `merge()` accepts only two DFs, so you would have to repeat it (N-1) times where `N` is the # of DFs to join

Comment: Thanks a lot Max, yeh I guess I will just do merge coz my supervisor doesn't want concat but your renaming works !!

Comment: @maxU could you help me dissolving your equation into only rename?

Comment: before doing merge, coz I guess what you did was make the 3 datasets as a matrix but I think I need to make separate 3 matrixes for my merge ... Thanks!!

Comment: @Nora, could you post small (3-5 rows each) reproducible data sets and your desired data set in your question?

Comment: sure! I will revise it within 1 min

Comment: oh I will generate separate question on it

Answer (score 1):

by using `reduce`

```
data1516=data1516.rename(columns={"Employer: ID" : "EID"})    
data1617=data1617.rename(columns={"Employer: ID" : "EID"})    
data1718=data1718.rename(columns={"Employer: ID" : "EID"})  

l=[data1516,data1617,data1718]
import functools 
df=functools.reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'EID'), l)
```

Comment: Tried use this, but still key errors. btw thanks for letting me remind function tools! what a beginner